# breeze: how to filter collection in count condition

Tags: collections, breeze, predicate

I have a class named A, it has a property B who is a collection of class C,
and I want to filter some records of A by A.B.count > 0, below is my tried queries:

```
breeze.Predicate.create("B().length", ">", 0);
breeze.Predicate.create("B()[0]", "!=", null);
breeze.Predicate.create("B()","all","length", ">", 0);
```

I got the error:TypeError: this._fnNode1 is null

i want to know what is the right way to filter the records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, i find another way to get the goal:

```
breeze.Predicate.create("B", "any", "value", "==", "myValue");
```

value: a property of c

myValue: some value meet my requirement

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Breeze supports aggregates yet, so you can't use something like count() in your query. Remember too that the Breeze predicate is being sent to the server for evaluation and it won't know about any Javascript properties like .length.

It looks like there is a way to do what you want described in the documentation:

http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/querying-depth

Take a look at the ***Getting just the Count*** section.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks mhand, i think you are right,seems breeze does not support the way i want.